# Should I create a sub table for the header table

Tags: t-sql

My question is should I create a sub table that would contain the following

```
ProductDocumentCountry
    [Product_Document_Id] NOT NULL,
    [Country_Code] [bit] NOT NULL,

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = USA

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = CHN

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = GER
```

or should I create a column and store the countries as a string with a delimiter.

```
Country_String = USA, CHN, GER
```

What is the base way to handle this type of layout.

```
ProductDocument
    [Product_Document_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Active_Ind] [bit] NULL,
```

Product_Document_Id = 1221

```
ProductDocumentDescription
    [Product_Document_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Country_Code] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Document_Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Sort_Code] [int] NULL,

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = USA
Sequence_Id = 1

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = CHN
Sequence_Id = 1

Product_Document_Id = 1221
Country_Code = GER
Sequence_Id = 1
```

I have a web page that is based on the ProductDocument table that will allow a user to select the different countries that can be created in the ProductDocumentDescription table.

The ProductDocumentDescription display a drop down list based on the ProductDocument selected countries.

Comment: I would not recommend creating a column and store the countries as a string with a delimiter. I would create an associate table and represent the M:M relationship in that. so your first approach ProductDocumentCountry is the right idea

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Kamran